# How do I access this array or object and bind to dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this string/object generated by a web method

```
[
  {
    "id": 367,
    "location": "Gagra"
  },
  {
    "id": 368,
    "location": "Gudauta"
  },
  {
    "id": 369,
    "location": "Sukhumi"
  },
  {
    "id": 370,
    "location": "Gulripshi"
  },
  {
    "id": 371,
    "location": "Ochamchira"
  },
  {
    "id": 372,
    "location": "Tkvarcheli"
  },
  {
    "id": 373,
    "location": "Gali"
  }
]
```

The Web Method is

```
 <WebMethod()>
Public Function PopulateStates(ByVal idLocation As Integer) As String
    Dim Locations As List(Of LocationData) = New List(Of LocationData)
    Dim JSONString As String
    Dim adp As New StatesTableAdapter
    Dim ds As StatesDataTable = adp.GetStatesByCountry(idLocation)
    If ds.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row As StatesRow In ds
            Dim ld As LocationData = New LocationData With {
                .id = row.idState,
                .location = row.locName
            }
            Locations.Add(ld)
        Next
    End If
    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Locations, Formatting.Indented)
    Return JSONString
End Function

Public Class LocationData
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property location As String
End Class
```

This what my ajax call looks like

```
    $('#ddlCountry').change(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/TestWebService.asmx/PopulateStates",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"idLocation":"' + $(this).val() + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            console.log(result.d);
            $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                $("#ddlState").append($("<option></option>").val(value.id).html(value.location));
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
        }
    });
});
```

});

When the string attempts to bind to the State Dropdownlist I get an error that reads
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [

Is my problem in the Web Method or am I not processing the results correctly?

Answer (score 0):

is console.log(result.d) return the array like mentionned in your description?